# Visual Basic Sequential Access Files

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on this assignment for quite awhile, but I'm practically ripping my hair out. Before anyone jumps the gun and says I'm looking for a free handout on the assignment, please note, I've done 90% of the assignment! The program has 4 commercials in a list, you choose which one to vote for and it saves your vote and tallies it. As it tallies it in the program, it also saves it into a file. The next time you open the file, you can hit "Display vote" and it reads the file and re-tally's everything for the user.

[image: Image of OP's Form]

Here's what the program looks like, at least what I have done. My issue is that when I hit display votes, nothing happens. It doesn't read in anything from the file. I tested using a message box for it to see if it displays anything from the file, and it does infact display the first item from the project. Anyone have any ideas?!

```
Public Class frmMain

Dim intVotes(3) As Integer


Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    lstCom.Items.Add("Budweiser")
    lstCom.Items.Add("FedEx")
    lstCom.Items.Add("E*Trade")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Pepsi")
    lstCom.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveVote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveVote.Click


    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim intSub As Integer




    intSub = lstCom.SelectedIndex

    If intSub <= intVotes.GetUpperBound(0) Then
        intVotes(intSub) += 1

        If IO.File.Exists("CallerVotes.txt") Then
            outFile = IO.File.CreateText("CallerVotes.txt")
            If lstCom.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                outFile.WriteLine("Budweiser")
            ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                outFile.WriteLine("FedEx")

            ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                outFile.WriteLine("E*TRADE")
            ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                outFile.WriteLine("Pepsi")
            End If
            outFile.Close()
        End If
    End If


    lblBud.Text = intVotes(0).ToString
    lblFed.Text = intVotes(1).ToString
    lblET.Text = intVotes(2).ToString
    lblPep.Text = intVotes(3).ToString


End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCom.SelectedIndexChanged


End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplayVote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayVote.Click



    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strText As String

    If IO.File.Exists("CallerVotes.txt") Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("CallerVotes.txt")
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            strText = inFile.ReadLine
            If strText = "Budweiser" Then
                intVotes(0) += 1
            ElseIf strText = "FedEx" Then
                intVotes(1) += 1
            ElseIf strText = "E*TRADE" Then
                intVotes(2) += 1
            ElseIf strText = "Pepsi" Then
                intVotes(3) += 1
            End If
        Loop
        inFile.Close()
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are not assigning the values from the intVotes array to the labels. At the end of `btnDisplayVote_Click` try adding

```
lblBud.Text = intVotes(0).ToString
lblFed.Text = intVotes(1).ToString
lblET.Text = intVotes(2).ToString
lblPep.Text = intVotes(3).ToString
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you so much! Such a small oversight. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your file I think you will see that you have only one entry. You are overwriting the file each time you click the save button by using the [`CreateText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

from MSDN(*emphasis mine*)

> This method is equivalent to the StreamWriter(String, Boolean) constructor overload with the append parameter set to false. If the file specified by path does not exist, it is created. If the file does exist, **its contents are overwritten**.

try using the [`AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead.

i.e.

```
If IO.File.Exists("CallerVotes.txt") Then
            outFile = IO.File.AppendText("CallerVotes.txt")
```

You will also need to assign the values that you read in to the appropriate labels per DeanOC's answer.